# How to improve execution time for controller.get_callable

Tags: performance, symfony4

Just installed a new symfony flex project using the web skeleton. I added a controller and a service to talk to the Prismic API.

Rendering a simple documtent from Prismic, I noticed the total execution time increasing a bit. When looking at the performance log, it seems that the largest execution time is spent on controller.get_callable.

Since I don't see any sub calls, how could I improve this so the execution time get's lower?

[image: Performance log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That time is related to the HttpKernel ControllerResolver, which decides which Controller to call depending on the request. You can improve the timing by optimizing your routes, making sure the system doesn't have to spend a huge amount of time resolving which controller/action to call.

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/http_kernel_controller_resolver.html